Invocable Action: How to return a string collection back to a flow
I am trying to use an Invocable action to make a callout to a webservice to return business event(be) codes associated with a policy. One policy may have one 'be' code or many 'be' codes. I need to return the collection of 'be' codes to the flow so that I can check for 5 special codes that may be attached to a policy.
Here is the my code:
@InvocableMethod(label='BE Notes Lookup' description='BE Notes Lookup' callout=True category='FIA Invocable')
    public static List<List<FlowOutputVariables>> beNoteCodes(List<FlowInput> flowInputs) {
        List<FlowOutputVariables> outputToReturn = new List<FlowOutputVariables>();
        List<List<FlowOutputVariables>> beNotesToReturn = new List<List<FlowOutputVariables>>();
        
        String inputRecId = flowInputs.get(0).recordId;
        System.debug('the input record id is =========================================: '+inputRecId);


        ***<< Http Request code to call webserivce - This works as designed >>***


        
                String responseBody = beNotesRes.getBody();
                SRV_businessEventParser parsedResponse = SRV_businessEventParser.parse(responseBody);
                
            
                if(parsedResponse.businessEventSearchResultsList != null && parsedResponse.businessEventSearchResultsList[0].businessEventList != null){
                    for(SRV_businessEventParser.businessEventList beResults : parsedResponse.businessEventSearchResultsList[0].businessEventList){

                       FlowOutputVariables returnVars = new FlowOutputVariables();
                        returnVars.beControlNum = beResults.beControlNum;
                        returnVars.beCodeNum = beResults.beCode;
                        returnVars.beDescription = beResults.beDescription;
                        returnVars.beSourceCode = beResults.beSourceCode;
                        returnVars.beStatusDescription = beResults.beStatusDescription;
                        returnVars.beClosedDate = beResults.beClosedDate;
                        returnVars.beReceivedDate = beResults.beReceivedDate;

                        outputToReturn.add(returnVars);
                    }
                    
                }   
                beNotesToReturn.add(outputToReturn);
                System.debug('the list of lists of beNotes to return are: '+beNotesToReturn);
                return beNotesToReturn;
            }
    }


    public class FlowInput{
        @InvocableVariable(label='Record ID' required=true)
        public String recordId;
    }


    public class FlowOutputVariables{
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='be Code')
        public String beCodeNum;

        @InvocableVariable(label='be Control Number')
        public Integer beControlNum;
        
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='be Description')
        public String beDescription;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='be Source Code')
        public String beSourceCode;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='be Status Description')
        public String beStatusDescription;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='be Received Date')
        public String beReceivedDate;
        
        @InvocableVariable(label='be Closed Date')
        public String beClosedDate;
        
    }

I am returning the List<List<FlowOutputVariables>> to the flow, but I cannot store Output Values to a variable. It won't keep a value in the box highlighted below.

Alternatively, if I uncheck the box "Manually assign variables" on the apex action and then try to add a loop element below the apex action, I cannot find the collection variable from the BE Notes Lookup apex action.

If I return List<FlowOutputVariables> in the invocable method, the flow will allow me to store the values manually, but when I try to debug the flow I get the message:
An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow
An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more information.
and this is displayed on the right side of the debug screen:

Is it not possible to return a list of values back to the flow that are not Salesforce objects?  In this case I'm returning strings which should be a valid return type.

Make FlowOutputVariables an outer class and add @AuraEnabled / @InvocableVariable to each field; see this answer

thank you cropredy! Your suggestions worked.  I should have posted here a week ago instead of beating my head against the wall.
